# Fit image within link to container height

Tags: html, css

What the `.image` element needs to do is adjust dynamically to both vertical and horizontal browser resizing. The `.link` element must also surround only the `.image` element (i.e., `height: 100%` cannot be used on the `.link` element).

The problem is that both the `.link` and `.image` elements extend beyond the bottom of the `.container` when the height of `.image` exceeds the height of `.container`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.component {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  min-height: calc(100vh / 3);
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.link {
  width: 480px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='component'>
    <div class='container'>
      <a href='#' class='link'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150' class='image' />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.component {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh / 3);
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.link {
  width: 480px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh / 3);
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="link">
          <img
            src="https://empresas.blogthinkbig.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Imagen3-245003649.jpg"
            class="image"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. The entire image needs to be visible at all times. This solution still has overflow at the top and bottom of the container.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use `display:flex` on `.link` ?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.component {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  min-height: calc(100vh / 3);
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.link {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex /*Add this*/
}

.image {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='component'>
    <div class='container'>
      <a href='#' class='link'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150' class='image' />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Still no good. The link is now larger than the image.